# Get Pixel with Magic++

Tags: c++, imagemagick

Can anybody show me an example how i get the pixel values of an Image ?
I want to read an Image and iterate over it .. and print out the actual "red" value.

Can anyone help ?
i'm a beginner :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a direct function in magic++ called read in the image class:

`image::read`

i.e   image.read( 640, 480, "RGB", CharPixel, pixels );

in which pixels will give you arrays of pixel values... that you can use later.

Or you can access direct low level pixels.. Here is how...
http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Image++.html#Raw%20Image%20Pixel%20Access